# EF Value Conversions for multiple columns

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I have a DB-First approach in the project, so i have to do some manual EF mappings. Is there any way for EF Value Conversion to do a conversion for multiple columns into one record?
All the examples in the documentation are for one property only.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations

Items Table:

| Id | ITM_Price | ITM_Currency | ITM_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 420 | USD | Item name |

Example:

```
public class Item
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Price Price { get; set; }
}
```

```
public record Price(decimal Value, string Currency);
```

The current EntityTypeBuilder is for the `Item`.

```
       builder
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .HasColumnName("ITM_Name");

       builder
            .Property(e => e.Price)
            .HasColumnName("ITM_Price")
            .HasColumnType("decimal(25, 6)")
            .HasConversion(
                v => v,
                v => new Price(v, ???)); // Can't set the currency via constructor / property initialization;
```

I'd like to keep the configuration in the config for `Item` mapping two columns into this record but if it's not possible do I require to create a seperate config for Price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution for that.

Instead of using conversion, the Owned Entity Types are a good match to solve that issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#mapping-owned-types-with-table-splitting